# Running two instances of the same node.js app on two different servers.

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to run my game for the west coast, and the east coast. How can I set it up so I can have it running on two servers yet using the same domain?

The way my code works is app.js is ran on the server and the home route is the game.. so all you do is type in gametitle.com and it loads up the game

Answer (score 2):

This is an architectural thing, not something specific to node.js. If you want to run the same process in two different regions on different VMs (say, for example, in two AWS regions), you'll just need a mechanism to coordinate the two at the DNS level. That could be through a load balancer, messaging queue, or through a ton of other different ways. It depends heavily on the specific needs of your application

Comment: I looked a lot into load balancing after reading this, but that seems to be more "Randomly find another server"

Comment: There are many different strategies you might use to route traffic to a server or over a network of servers; geo, latency, failover, round-robin. It's should never be "randomly find another server"